# Extract video URL from NSNotification Asset

Tags: swift

I have a small question for big programmers just like you:)

I'm building IOS application using Swift 2 and I have a video player which works fine, I just want to get the current video url using nsnotification as following.

```
      in viewDidLoad()

    // add notification
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(MZAvailableDownloadsViewController.videoHasStarted(_:)), name: "AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification", object: nil)
    }

    func videoHasStarted(notification: NSNotification) {
       print(notification.object?.asset)
       // HOW TO EXTRACT VIDEO URL?
    }
```

The output is:

```
Optional(<AVURLAsset: 0x7faa81c02e20, URL = http://www.emanway.com/media/2016/06/22/17_Elahi.mp4>)
```

as you can see, how can I get the video url from the output? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry for that, this is the first time I use stackoverflow :)

Comment: you can find video VideoURL from WKWebView ?

Answer (score 1):

AVURLAsset has an [URL property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVURLAsset_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVURLAsset/URL).

To use it, cast your object to AVURLAsset instead of AnyObject.

Something like this should work:

```
if let asset = notification.object?.asset as? AVURLAsset {
    let videoURL = asset.URL

}
```