# Is it possible to access system classes in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I was trying to access the player inside `WKWebView` but I did some coding and it turned out it doesn't use `AVPlayerViewController` it uses a system class called `WebFullScreenVideoRootVideoController`

I used the code like this

[image]

the function in the picture is fired after a UIWindow appears

---

After that I started digging more and search for notifications fired by `WebFullScreenVideoRootVideoController` and some class called `AVSystemController` or something like that... it turned out it has multiple notifications two of them logically do what I want:

```
NowPlayingAppIsPlayingDidChange // first one
SomeClientPlayingDidChange // second one
```

But also the object that they return is called `FigBaseObject`

Is there anyway to access these objects "some hacky way :P" ?

Comment: even if it is, its Private API and your app might be rejected for using that, also it might break when Apple releases new iOS.

Comment: does that mean it is impossible to access the url of that player? // If there is any way you know how to access WKWebView video url that would be great to know ...

Comment: you can access URL of WKWebView and get the video,, if that does not help you,  You can use Javascript ( - evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:  ) and do whatever you want with the actual HTML content.

Comment: did you ever find a way to access these classes?

Comment: @SPatrickApps unfortunately no, mate.

Comment: what is the name of this notification from WebFullScreenVideoRootVideoController can you tell me ? i'm working on this task so please help me ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55377677/how-to-detect-avplayer-and-get-url-of-current-video-from-wkwebview this is my question if you know please answer me.

Comment: @ogres how can do this with javascript can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you to find when to work on particular notification.

http://paulofierro.com/blog/2015/10/12/listening-for-video-playback-within-a-wkwebview

inside the notification, you can find the url
[Extract video URL from NSNotification Asset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38025045/extract-video-url-from-nsnotification-asset)

```
if let asset = notification.object?.asset as? AVURLAsset {
   let videoURL = asset.URL

}
```

Did test for XAMAarin IOS, notification.object?.asset is not available, but not sure about swift.

Thanks